# How to set default location when calling amazon client

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have code base running in Amazon EC2 instances, and it will read region, and other access keys and all from there itself. So while creating the client I don't need to pass any thing, I can just use empty contructor.

```
// Empty Constructor
private static AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient _logClient;
public static AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient logClient =>
_logClient ?? (_logClient = new AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient());
```

But my manager wants a FALL BACK location to be set to US-EAST-1 , if my code base fails to read somehow find/read the region from ECS. How to acheive that.

Can I do something like below.

```
 private static AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient _logClient;
 public static AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient logClient => 
_logClient ?? (_logClient = new AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient(RegionEndPoint.USEAST1));
```

You can see I added a region, but if I do this I think it will overwrite the region that will be passed by EC2 instance. Am I right? All I want is to be able to have a fall back region. How to set that. please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using the AWS .Net SDK you can generate an XML config file to include in your project. In that config file you can set the default region as needed.

Amazon has some information about setting the default region here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-ref.html